# Java SparkSession Hive SQL is not applying regexp_replace

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive

I have a working Spark application executing hive queries.

With new requirements, I need to remove all whitespaces from the selected key.

According to [Apache documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) `regexp_replace` is suitable for my case:

> `regexp_replace(string INITIAL_STRING, string PATTERN, string REPLACEMENT)`
>   Returns the string resulting from replacing all substrings in INITIAL_STRING that match the java regular expression syntax defined in PATTERN with instances of REPLACEMENT. > For example, `regexp_replace("foobar", "oo|ar", "")` returns `'fb.'` Note that some care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using `'\s'` as the second argument will match the letter s; `'\\s'` is necessary to match whitespace, etc.

Running this:

```
public class SparkSql {

    private SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("hive-sql")
            .config("spark.config.option", "configuration")
            .enableHiveSupport()
            .getOrCreate();

    // Omitted code here ...

    public void execute() {
        Dataset<Row> dataset = session.sql("select regexp_replace(master_key, '\\s+', ''") as key from master_table);
        JavaRDD<Row> rdd = context.parallelize(dataset.collectAsList(), factor);

        for (Row row : rdd.collect())
            System.out.println(row.getString(row.fieldIndex("key")));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ABCD 100000
```

Expected:

```
ABCD100000
```

For some reason, `regexp_replace` was not applied.
What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first attempt to find the reason was to check if query is runnable in other environments.

Hive Shell returned expected result for `select regexp_replace(master_key, '\\s+', '')`.

`\` is an escape character and if the hive shell requires one escape character, using this expression as Java `String` will require one more escape character to pass `\` to `SparkSession`'s SQL parser.

So, this `Dataset<Row> dataset = session.sql("select regexp_replace(master_key, '\\s+', ''") as key from master_table);` wil actually pass `\s+` to SQL parser:

```
public void execute() {
    Dataset<Row> dataset = session.sql("select regexp_replace("test", '\\s+', ''") as key from master_table);
    JavaRDD<Row> rdd = context.parallelize(dataset.collectAsList(), factor);

    for (Row row : rdd.collect())
        System.out.println(row.getString(row.fieldIndex("key")));
}
```

Output:

```
test
```

To pass `\\s+` to `SparkSession`'s SQL parser we need to add one escape `\` character per `\`:

```
public void execute() {
    Dataset<Row> dataset = session.sql("select regexp_replace(master_key, '\\\\s+', ''") as key from master_table);
    JavaRDD<Row> rdd = context.parallelize(dataset.collectAsList(), factor);

    for (Row row : rdd.collect())
        System.out.println(row.getString(row.fieldIndex("key")));
}
```

Output:

```
ABCD100000
```